# Generate Wordpress posts

Tags: database, wordpress

Is there any way to generate posts/pages for Wordpress? I have a seperate database with information I would like to use. For example, I would like to create the posts with the ID from my own database as link in Wordpress.

I think this is the way: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post although I have no idea where to put this. functions.php or post.php? And is it possible to call it on intervals? Maybe through a cronjob.

If anyone can point me in the right direction/confirm that I am on the right path that would be very helpfull.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the ID of your own Database has the same format as the Wordpress one? You can use wp_insert_post with a cronjob but you need to add the wp header in your php file. After this you need to check if the id is already used with get_post() before insert it..

Comment: They do not have the same ID's. The ID I use should be used as the link in Wordpress. For example:in my database I have information with ID 7832648723, this should be used in wordpress as a post or page witl link http://mysite.com/7832648723. But if it's to much work I'll figure something out.

Comment: I think you'll need to find another way to do your project, this way is way too much complicated to be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `wp_insert_post` is the correct function, but the code should be in [your own Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

And then set up a WP Cron Job with [`wp_schedule_event`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)